# How to convert time format in numeric in R

Tags: r

This is what the sample looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   trip_id start_time          end_time           
     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1       1 2020-10-05 11:11:36 2020-10-05 12:12:54
 2       2 2020-10-05 16:09:16 2020-10-05 20:00:42
 3       3 2020-10-05 09:16:33 2020-10-05 11:16:27
 4       4 2020-10-05 14:16:38 2020-10-05 14:37:38
 5       5 2020-10-05 13:08:16 2020-10-05 13:13:16
 6       6 2020-10-05 11:02:23 2020-10-05 13:04:16
 7       7 2020-10-05 13:15:19 2020-10-05 15:54:19
 8   56562 2020-10-09 11:05:25 2020-10-09 13:37:44
 9   56563 2020-10-09 14:11:30 2020-10-09 14:12:30
10   56564 2020-10-09 16:00:40 2020-10-09 16:46:58
```

```
data <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 56562L,56563L, 56564L), start_time = structure(c(1601896296, 1601914156,1601889393, 1601907398, 1601903296, 1601895743, 1601903719, 1602241525,1602252690, 1602259240), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), end_time = structure(c(1601899974, 1601928042, 1601896587,1601908658, 1601903596, 1601903056, 1601913259, 1602250664, 1602252750,1602262018), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Based on my question above, I want to create other columns which convert my time columns into a numeric value. I think there are many ways to convert it. For example, it may take the `second` from 0 o'clock or an `hour` from 0 o'clock or a `minute` from 0 o'clock. `6 o'clock` is represented as `3600` seconds from 0 o'clock.

Therefore, any package and function can do this?
Is there another appropriate way to convert my time columns data to numeric values?
I want to focus only on my time (dates are no count).
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use lubridate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("time"),  ymd_hms)) %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("time"), ~ as.numeric(.), .names = "{.col}.{.fn}"))
```

Output:

```
   trip_id start_time          end_time            start_time.1 end_time.1
     <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1       1 2020-10-05 11:11:36 2020-10-05 12:12:54   1601896296 1601899974
 2       2 2020-10-05 16:09:16 2020-10-05 20:00:42   1601914156 1601928042
 3       3 2020-10-05 09:16:33 2020-10-05 11:16:27   1601889393 1601896587
 4       4 2020-10-05 14:16:38 2020-10-05 14:37:38   1601907398 1601908658
 5       5 2020-10-05 13:08:16 2020-10-05 13:13:16   1601903296 1601903596
 6       6 2020-10-05 11:02:23 2020-10-05 13:04:16   1601895743 1601903056
 7       7 2020-10-05 13:15:19 2020-10-05 15:54:19   1601903719 1601913259
 8   56562 2020-10-09 11:05:25 2020-10-09 13:37:44   1602241525 1602250664
 9   56563 2020-10-09 14:11:30 2020-10-09 14:12:30   1602252690 1602252750
10   56564 2020-10-09 16:00:40 2020-10-09 16:46:58   1602259240 1602262018
```

Answer (score 3):

They *are* numbers, just convert them using `as.number`: the result is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00.  If you want to check:

```
data$start_time[1]
[1] "2020-10-05 11:11:36 UTC"

as.numeric(data$start_time)[1]
[1] 1601896296

as.POSIXct(1601896296, tz="UTC", origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2020-10-05 11:11:36 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

The below line of code will help convert the time difference between a sample start time and end time into seconds.

You can make use of this and modify according to your needs. the gist being you will be using `as.numeric` method and `as.POSIXct`

`as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2007-05-17 09:00:00")-as.POSIXct("2007-05-07 09:00:00"), units="secs")`