# How to convert Hour: minutes: seconds to decimal number in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

According to my lastest question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726306/how-to-convert-time-format-in-numeric-in-r)

I want to convert a column into the data.frame in date format to decimal number. However, I want to find another way but using the number of seconds from POSIXct. We can be multiplying this vector by `c(1, 1/60, 1/3600)` For example `02:20:00` will turn to `2.333333` Can I compute this into my data?

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   trip_id start_time          end_time           
     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1       1 2020-10-05 11:11:36 2020-10-05 12:12:54
 2       2 2020-10-05 16:09:16 2020-10-05 20:00:42
 3       3 2020-10-05 09:16:33 2020-10-05 11:16:27
 4       4 2020-10-05 14:16:38 2020-10-05 14:37:38
 5       5 2020-10-05 13:08:16 2020-10-05 13:13:16
 6       6 2020-10-05 11:02:23 2020-10-05 13:04:16
 7       7 2020-10-05 13:15:19 2020-10-05 15:54:19
 8   56562 2020-10-09 11:05:25 2020-10-09 13:37:44
 9   56563 2020-10-09 14:11:30 2020-10-09 14:12:30
10   56564 2020-10-09 16:00:40 2020-10-09 16:46:58
```

```
data <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 56562L,56563L, 56564L), start_time = structure(c(1601896296, 1601914156,1601889393, 1601907398, 1601903296, 1601895743, 1601903719, 1602241525,1602252690, 1602259240), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), end_time = structure(c(1601899974, 1601928042, 1601896587,1601908658, 1601903596, 1601903056, 1601913259, 1602250664, 1602252750,1602262018), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R Base.

```
df <- read.csv(text ="start_time    end_time
05/10/2020 11:11:36 05/10/2020 12:12:54
05/10/2020 16:09:16 05/10/2020 20:00:42
05/10/2020 09:16:33 05/10/2020 11:16:27
05/10/2020 14:16:38 05/10/2020 14:37:38
05/10/2020 13:08:16 05/10/2020 13:13:16
05/10/2020 11:02:23 05/10/2020 13:04:16
05/10/2020 13:15:19 05/10/2020 15:54:19
09/10/2020 11:05:25 09/10/2020 13:37:44
09/10/2020 14:11:30 09/10/2020 14:12:30
09/10/2020 16:00:40 09/10/2020 16:46:58
", sep="\t" )


df$test <- lapply(str_split(str_sub(df$start_time,12), ":"),  
                  function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(x)) * c(1,1/60, 1/3600)))
df


            start_time            end_time     test
1  05/10/2020 11:11:36 05/10/2020 12:12:54 11.19333
2  05/10/2020 16:09:16 05/10/2020 20:00:42 16.15444
3  05/10/2020 09:16:33 05/10/2020 11:16:27 9.275833
4  05/10/2020 14:16:38 05/10/2020 14:37:38 14.27722
5  05/10/2020 13:08:16 05/10/2020 13:13:16 13.13778
6  05/10/2020 11:02:23 05/10/2020 13:04:16 11.03972
7  05/10/2020 13:15:19 05/10/2020 15:54:19 13.25528
8  09/10/2020 11:05:25 09/10/2020 13:37:44 11.09028
9  09/10/2020 14:11:30 09/10/2020 14:12:30 14.19167
10 09/10/2020 16:00:40 09/10/2020 16:46:58 16.01111
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your math requirement completely, but will this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(dec = as.numeric(strftime(start_time, format = '%H', tz = 'UTC')) * 1  
                as.numeric(strftime(start_time, format = '%M', tz = 'UTC'))/60 + 
                as.numeric(strftime(start_time, format = '%H', tz = 'UTC'))/3600)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   trip_id start_time          end_time              dec
     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
 1       1 2020-10-05 11:11:36 2020-10-05 12:12:54 11.2 
 2       2 2020-10-05 16:09:16 2020-10-05 20:00:42 16.2 
 3       3 2020-10-05 09:16:33 2020-10-05 11:16:27  9.27
 4       4 2020-10-05 14:16:38 2020-10-05 14:37:38 14.3 
 5       5 2020-10-05 13:08:16 2020-10-05 13:13:16 13.1 
 6       6 2020-10-05 11:02:23 2020-10-05 13:04:16 11.0 
 7       7 2020-10-05 13:15:19 2020-10-05 15:54:19 13.3 
 8   56562 2020-10-09 11:05:25 2020-10-09 13:37:44 11.1 
 9   56563 2020-10-09 14:11:30 2020-10-09 14:12:30 14.2 
10   56564 2020-10-09 16:00:40 2020-10-09 16:46:58 16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `difftime()` function by subtracting the date object from the datetime object.

For example:

```
difftime(data$start_time, as.Date(data$start_time))
#or to specify the units
difftime(data$start_time, as.Date(data$start_time), units= "day")
```